# How to detect another value of two-dimensional array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Consider I have this array :

```
[[x, y], [a, b]]
```

My question is if I detect `x`, can I access `y` in JavaScript?
My code is not as simple as this code, I just made an example.

Comment: You have access to the array, don't you? So you know where and what `y` is.

Comment: Can't you just use Map ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#Examples

Comment: use objects instead

Comment: @elenaa I just know `x` and want to know can I access of `y` thorugh `x` or not.

Comment: @jalal246 Object is the only solution? Can't I do that with Arrays ?

Comment: @beso9595 No problem is not about iterating.

Comment: No, this is why objects are used for. If the data is in array then you have to convert it to objects then inquire it by keys which represent the X value

Comment: Can you please give us more context? There are so many ways this could be handled but it's hard to help without knowing what you are trying to do.

Comment: @jalal246 I'm with you Jalal, Thanks ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var items = [
  [1, 2],
  [3, 4],
  [5, 6]
];

items.forEach(function(val,index){
if(val.includes(3)){ //Lets say we have 3
console.log(val[1])} //get the second value i.e 4
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I found final solution without Objects.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to use an object for this rather than a 2d array:

```
let obj = {
  x: y,
  a: b
}
```

In this case, `x` points to the value `y` and `a` points to the value `b`

Here is a practical example:

```js
let countries = {
  "US": "United States",
  "AUS": "Australia",
  "UK": "United Kingdom"
}

console.log(countries["US"]);
console.log(countries["AUS"]);
console.log(countries["UK"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `x` value must be an object with a reference to either `y` or their parent container.